# How to know if a webtable cell is Read Only via UFT?

Tags: vbscript, vb6, qtp, hp-uft

I have a webtable that some of the cells are Read Only(they have text inside)

and I want to indicate that via UFT.

Is there a property that can indicate that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% clear on what you're asking.

By default table cells are not editable, in order for the cell to be editable it should either be an `input` element (or `textarea`) or have its [`contenteditable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_Editable) attribute set to `true` (am I missing an option here?).

If the cell contains an `input` (or `textarea`) element, UFT will identify it as a `WebEdit` which supports the `disabled` property. If it's a regular cell (`td`) with `contenteditable` set to `true` then you can check that property via UFT directly.

Comment: Hi Motti,I will explain. the web table has cells which contains text, if the cell is editable, so there is a webedit inside a webelement. if the cell is not editable, there is only a webelement inside the cell.

Comment: so the webedit is an indication if the cell is editable or not. but i thought maybe there is a simple way - like an property in order to know if the cell is editable or not.

Comment: @thechmodmaster the simplest way I can think of is to do a `ChildObjects` with the description of a `WebEdit` and see if it returns any elements.

Comment: i tried that already and it do return a WebEdit object even if the cell is not editable.

Comment: @thechmodmaster in that case inspect the WebEdit to see if it's visible / disabled